# Excel get parameters (not table) from a stored procedure SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, excel-2013

An SQL server 2012 stored procedure has three parameters:

1. INPUT parameter (named UUT)
2. OUTPUT parameter (named StartDate)
3. OUTPUT parameter (named EndDate)

There is no table output.

An Excel 2013 access to the stored procedure via DATA/From Other Sources/From SQL Query

```
{CALL [databasename].[dbo].[uspStoredProcedureName] (?,?,?)}
```

I have three parameters as the SQL engine will not allow me to enter only one parameter.
The output is an empty table (as expected), but no parameters...

What is the correct way to enter only the input parameter and get the two outputs?

Comment: It might sound defeatist, but I'm considering to change the stored procedure as to have the dates as an output table... If it works I'll suggest this as a solution - but I won't be proud of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no better answer presents itself...

The only way I found to get the parameters was to select them as to have a table output. I found no way to get parameters output.

- Add to the stored procedure:

`SELECT @pStartDate AS StartDate, @pEndDate as EndDate`

- optionally, check if the outputs are valid (debug only - you can't read this from excel)

`IF @pStartDate IS NULL OR @pEndDate IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @responseMessage = 'No data was read, check inputs'
    END`

- In excel, it will be pasted as two adjustment cells with headers (e.g. the field names will appear on A1 and B1, the values on A2 and B2)